# Get Fail2Ban To Check findtime Every X Minutes

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, fail2ban, brute-force-attacks

I have `fail2ban` set up with the following settings:

```
bantime  = 86400
findtime  = 600
maxretry = 2
```

This is great as it stops any IPs who are brute forcing 3 times within 10 minutes. However, there are IPs that are attempting every 30 mins or so. To catch those IPs, I changed the settings to:

```
bantime  = 86400
findtime  = 3600
maxretry = 2
```

Now, it checks every hour and catches some of those IPs that were trying every 20-30 minutes. However, now my VPS is not catching IPs who might be brute forcing at a high level for one hour.

Thus, is there any way to set the `findtime = 3600` and also have `fail2ban` check every 10 minutes?

Comment: fail2ban "checks" every time it processes a log entry. So I don't understand your question. What is it you want?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the question. I was under the impression that Fail2Ban checks logs at the same amount set by findtime. If this is not the case, do you know where to set the time interval for Fail2Ban to check a log? Also, please support the question with a vote if I provided a proper clarification. Thanks :-)

Comment: findtime is the interval in which maxretry matches must occur for the ban to trigger. The logs are read as they're written to disk. You seem to be asking to slow that down.

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned by Michael Hampton in a couple of comments, the [reaction time](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Reaction_time), how often `fail2ban` checks the logs, has nothing to do with the `findtime` parameter. `fail2ban` is expected to read new log data every second or so (it will depend on your computer load, but it should be really fast since in most cases new log data will still be in memory, in a kernel buffer.)

The `findtime=...` defines how far back logs are checked. The filter is checked against input that has a date between `now - findtime` and `now`. If the filter found `maxretry` or more lines of log that matched (not counting those that also match the `ignoreregex`) within that period of time (`now - findtime` to `now`), then it emits the `ban` action.

```
  ancient past  |     past       |       ban         |   future
----------------+--*--*-*--*---*-+-------------------+------------->
                |                |                   |
                |                |                   +--> now + bantime
                |                +--> now
                +--> now - findtime
```

There is a graph showing the timeline. Logs part of *ancient past* are ignored. Logs between `now - findtime` and `now`, section named *past*, are checked for matches. If the number of matches (represented by asterisks) is `>= maxretry` then a ban is started at `now`. The ban lasts until `now + bantime`. Note that hits with the same IP once the IP was banned should not happen for the port for which it was banned. It could still happen for other ports, though.

So by increasing the `findtime=...` you do not affect the reaction time, however, you increase the chance for an IP to get banned by the corresponding filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a jail in `jail.conf` to check who is brute forcing every 30 minutes. Example of working configuration is:

```
[ssh] # first jail: check every 10 minutes 

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
action   = %(action_)s
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
bantime  = 600

[fail2ban-ssh] # second jail: check every hour

enabled = true
filter = fail2ban-ssh
logpath = /var/log/fail2ban.log
action = iptables-multiport
maxretry = 3
findtime = 3600    
bantime = 86400     # ban for a day
```

Create a file `fail2ban-ssh.conf` and put it in `filter.d` to match what you wish, for example:

```
[Definition]

failregex = fail2ban.actions: WARNING \[ssh\] Unban <HOST>
```

Comment: As per answer from @Alexis Wilke, there is no need to have two services. The blocking is instant ie the the fail2ban daemon reads log all the time and the reaction is within 1 second or so with no connectivity to `findtime` or `bantime` parameter.